# How to solve these errors in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

09:25:28 AM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
09:25:28 AM  [main]     Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
09:25:28 AM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 7.2.11
09:25:28 AM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
09:25:28 AM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
09:25:28 AM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
09:25:28 AM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think
09:25:28 AM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
09:25:28 AM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
09:25:29 AM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
09:25:59 AM  [main]     All prerequisites found
09:25:59 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
09:25:59 AM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
09:25:59 AM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
09:25:59 AM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
09:25:59 AM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
09:25:59 AM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
09:25:59 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
09:25:59 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
09:26:07 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
09:26:07 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
09:26:17 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
09:26:18 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
09:27:31 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 5368)
09:27:31 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 11552)
09:27:31 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
09:27:32 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to stop MySQL app...
09:27:33 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
09:27:44 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
09:27:44 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
09:27:49 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running

Comment: The error is `Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"! MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port`.

Comment: If you don't need MySQL, ignore those errors, otherwise, do what's told by XAMPP error.